# Travel Visa best options

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

Does anyone out there have any information on me trying to apply for a British/UK visa to come and live and retire in the U.K.? I have been married to my British wife for 28 years and have been working and living in Germany for 25 years. I’m a retiree from the Army, working as a civilian now. If anyone out there knows how I should proceed with my application for a Visa with my application for a visa. Please let me know, I would appreciate any information available out there.

Comment: We can't do much for you, as we don't handle questions about long term residence. Our sister site [expatriates.se] would be more able to answer questions like this. But I think you should first Google "Surinder Singh" and act very quickly before Brexit becomes a reality.

Comment: This is a general tool to help identify the correct approach https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa